# On an upper bound of the diagonal entries of an orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

Let $X$ be an $n\times p$ matrix of full column rank and $H=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ be the orthogonal projection onto the column space of $X$. If $X$ has $c$ identical rows for some $c\leq n$, I want to prove that $h_{ii} \leq c^{-1}$ whenever $i$ is among the row indices of the $c$ identical rows.

I guess I need to start with the fact that correspoding rows in $H$ are also identical, but I don't really know **how to prove that**. Then it would be suitable to make use of the fact that $H$ is symmetrical and idempotent, so:
$$h_{ii}=\sum_{j=1}^nh_{ij}^2\ .$$
But I can't really make any progress from there. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: @user1551 $X$ is $nxp$ matrix, and $c \leq n$.

Comment: @user1551 done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the first $c$ rows of $X$ are identical to each other. Then we can express $X$ in the form of
$$
X=\pmatrix{ev^T\\ Y},
$$
where $e$ is the all-one vector of length $c$. Hence
$$
H=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T=\pmatrix{ev^T\\ Y}(cvv^T+Y^TY)^{-1}\pmatrix{ve^T&Y^T}.
$$
Therefore, for each $i\le c$, we have
\begin{align}
h_{ii}
&=v^T(cvv^T+Y^TY)^{-1}v\\
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}v^T(\varepsilon I_p+cvv^T+Y^TY)^{-1}v\\
&\le\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}v^T(\varepsilon I_p+cvv^T)^{-1}v\\
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\frac{\|v\|^2}{\varepsilon+c\|v\|^2}\\
&\le c^{-1}.
\end{align}
(I use an inequality sign instead of an equality sign on last line because because $v$ can be zero.)

Comment: this is impressive, thank you! Is it possible to get the same conclusion only from looking at the sum $\sum_{j=1}^n h_{ij}^2$?

Comment: @itsme Sorry, I don't know, but you may try to prove that a rank-one principal submatrix of an orthogonal projection has trace $\le1$. If this turns out to be true, since there are $c$ diagonal entries in your case, each $h_{ii}$ in your case is bounded above by $c^{-1}$.